# nodejs app integration with asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, node.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a nodejs app that acts as an online compiler for online coding practice and want to use it with my online education portal built with asp.net mvc 5. 
how can i integerate my node.js app to ASP.NET MVC5 ??

Comment: i have a running ASP.Net MVC 5 using node JS (running in node IIS) as my tier to access mssql, I want all the backend handled by node JS so I can reuse it to some other front-end applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs and ASP.NET MVC are completely apart. Nodejs uses JavaScript and ASP.NET uses .NET Framework libraries usable in a number of .NET languages. If you want the same Nodejs coding compilation functionality in .NET, I prefer to try to find the code compilation companions libraries in .NET or create a way such as getting the code from the form, compile and test in an action and return the output to the view (Ways like this) to help you built quickly.